# Map JSON String to JsonObject

Tags: scala, gson, objectmapper

I have a JSON string like

```
{
    "key1": "value1",
    "definition": {
     // JSON content here
    }
}
```

"definition" key in JSON can contains JSONArray, JSONObject. 
For example, it can have

```
"key2" : ""
```

or

```
"key2" : {}
```

or

```
"key2" : []
```

To accommodate this, I have created corresponding Scala class like

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject
class JsonData {
  var key1: String = _
  var definition: JsonObject = _
}
```

While mapping JSON string to class JsonData, I am getting "definition" in JsonData instance as empty.

Sample code:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.{DeserializationFeature, ObjectMapper}
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper
import com.google.gson.JsonObject

object TestMe {

  val mapper = new ObjectMapper with ScalaObjectMapper
  mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
  mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val jsonString = "{\"key1\": \"value1\",\"definition\": {\"key2\" : \"abc\"}}"
    val data = mapper.readValue[JsonData](jsonString)
    println(data.definition.getAsJsonObject()) //empty

    val jsonString1 = "{\"key1\": \"value1\",\"definition\": {\"key2\" : {\"key3\" : \"\"}}}"
    val data1 = mapper.readValue[JsonData](jsonString1)
    println(data1.definition.getAsJsonObject()) //empty

    val jsonString2 = "{\"key1\": \"value1\",\"definition\": {\"key2\" : [\"a\",\"b\"]}}"
    val data2 = mapper.readValue[JsonData](jsonString2)
    println(data2.definition.getAsJsonObject()) //empty
  }

  class JsonData {
    var key1: String = _
    var definition: JsonObject = _
  }
}
```

How can I read JSON string and map it to class which has one of its attribute type of JsonObject?

Versions:

```
Scala : 2.11
Jackson-core = 2.6.x;
Gson = 2.6.x;
Jackson-databind = 2.6.x;
Jackson-module-scala = 2.6.5;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode` instead of using Google's Gson `JsonObject` class. Using Jackson's own classes should make it pretty trivial.
Although you may just map to a `Map[String, Any]` instead for this kind of flexibility, unless you really need it to still be in Json.

Comment: thanks Sebastiaan. I just simplified JSON format to present problem simply. It is much more in nested form and I need to have class for same. Changing to JsonNode has solved my problem.

Comment: @user811602 yeah Google’s Gson class may also represent json, but not in a way that Jackson magically understands. I’m sure you COULD make some mapping that works, but it would be harder.